# Oracle APEX: How to solve session expired error in interactive report?

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I create a interactive report about project info, which has a link to a detailed page in another app (not in the same workspace) for every project in my interactive report. When I right click the link and choose 'open in a new tab' option, I will get "Your session ha expired" error if I get back to my own app and do click buttons. How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: You get 'Your session has expired' in the second app with the detailed page or in first app with the project info?

Comment: It is the first app with interactive report